# SQL exception : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

We are using Oracle as the database for our application. The application runs well after 12 PM , but before 12 PM  we get this "No more data to read from socket" error.

```
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [Here my sql query  ....]; 
No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
    at in.co.homecredit.smsSending.dao.PosContractUploadDaoImpl.readPosDetails(PosContractUploadDaoImpl.java:65)
    at in.co.homecredit.smsSending.ui.main.SmsSendingConfirmationView.prepareCenterComponent(SmsSendingConfirmationView.java:105)
    at in.co.homecredit.smsSending.ui.main.SmsSendingConfirmationView.enterAuthenticatedUser(SmsSendingConfirmationView.java:84)
    at in.co.homecredit.common.ui.main.AbstractMainView.enter(AbstractMainView.java:466)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:571)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:526)
    at in.co.homecredit.smsSending.ui.main.SmsSendingInputFormView$7.buttonClick(SmsSendingInputFormView.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:978)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:275)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
```

I tried lots of things like restart the server and all  but not able to fixed it .Can anybody please help me out  to resolved it .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Which Oracle version (full version!) and driver version are you using?

Comment: oracle version 11g and driver version 11.2.0

Comment: That is not the full version information. What is the full version of both?